# The real count is different from the result of collection.find() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Recently, I wrote a tiny app to query data from MongoDB with pymongo. The code as following shown

```
colls = collection.find({'created': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 14, 10),
                                     '$lt': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 14, 17)}},
                        {'created':1, '_id': 0})
print 'Totally count is ', colls.count()
```

So far, everything is okay. However,

```
results = []
for item in colls:
    results.append(item)
```

I found that the length of **results** is less than **colls.count()**. It was so strange? Why they are different?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running this in a sharded cluster and hitting [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645), your result suggests that there are more elements in the collection than are included in your find query.  To verify, just re-run the query without parameters:

```
colls = collection.find({}, {'created':1, '_id': 0});
```

Then compare that length with the count results.

If they differ, then just switch your predicates to see what values are outside the given range:

```
colls = collection.find({'created': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 14, 10),
                                     '$gt': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 14, 17)}},
                        {'created':1, '_id': 0})
```

If that gets you nothing, and you have an index on `created` then you may have non-datetime values in the index and only [one type will match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888207/1148648) when you query, so you could [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) a different index to make sure they are returned.

Comment: Hi Adam, No index created on `created`. And it is difficult to find out those are not in find query but have involved in count(). Does the find query lose data?

Comment: And I am not running in a sharded cluster