# A range query on a mixed-type field doesn't return all documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB and one of its field can have mixed-type values. Now I'd like to apply a range query on this field, but it doesn't return all matched documents.

Sorting all documents by `value` field returns number values followed by a string value, as described in [the document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

```
> db.test.find().sort({ value: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc639e498f5e13a42b0383"), "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc639e498f5e13a42b0384"), "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc639e498f5e13a42b0385"), "value" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc7757498f5e13a42b0386"), "value" : "3" }
```

But when I use a range query, it just returns documents whose `value` is of the same type as a value in the query. For example, the query below returns one document instead of two.

```
> db.test.find({ value: { $gte: 11 } }).sort({ value: 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc639e498f5e13a42b0385"), "value" : 11 }
```

Given [the document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte) says it uses the same comparison order as sorting for different BSON types, it feels strange for me.

Are there any ways to get all matched documents in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good data structure at all, but you're right that the behavior is odd and should probably be considered a documentation bug.

This behavior is documented in the [perl driver documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/perl/current/MongoDB/DataTypes.html) ("You must query for data using the correct type.") and explained in a [question related to indexing here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887727/mongodb-index-on-different-types). However, the behavior is the same with or without indexes.

I was able to reproduce this with MongoDB 3.0-rc2. With your data,

```
> db.mixedType.find({"value" : {$gt : ""}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc7757498f5e13a42b0386"), "value" : "3" }

> db.mixedType.find({"value" : {$gt : 10}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54dc639e498f5e13a42b0385"), "value" : 11 }.
```

So comparison of different types, setting numeric types aside, yields false. I also tried empty objects, empty arrays and boolean values, e.g. `$gt : false` will return a document with `value : true` and `$gte: {}` will return a document with `value : {}`.